# Is the new operator required in this case to create a new object?

Tags: javascript, object

I was going though this presentation http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/FRM08. Steve Anderson used a function having structure similar to the below.

```
function o(p) {
    return { n: p };
}
```

To create an object from function o he used

```
new o(123)
```

I guess there is no need of new operator in this case. You can simply write.

```
o(123)
```

What would be the difference in the two ways?

Answer (score 2):

The code doesn't make much sense. If the function is used without the `new` keyword it creates and returns a single object. If it's used with the `new` keyword, as in the example, two objects are created, and the object created inside the function is discarded.

If you return an object from the function, you should not use the `new` keyword. A function that is supposed to be used with the `new` keyword doesn't return an object, instead it uses the `this` keyword to set properties in the already created object:

```
function o(p) {
  this.n = p;
}
```

Comment: "the object created inside the function is discarded" If its discarded then how does the result of new o(123) have n as property with 123 as value?

Comment: @Cracker: Hm... It seems that it kind of works to return an object, as it will be used instead of the original, but then the object that is created before the function is run will be discarded instead. Also, the object won't inherit the prototype from the function.